Jasmine/Karma error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')" error after putting routerLink on Angular template
I am trying to make some tests in my Angular app, but when I add this line with routerLink, the tests gives me errors:
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="../loja-lista" role="tab" type="button">
<fa-icon [icon]="faArrowLeft" style="font-size: x-large; color: #225262"> </fa-icon>
</a>

package.json:
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    ...
    ...
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",

the error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')
    at new RouterLink (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2020/router.mjs:5711:40)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.factory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2020/router.mjs:5865:16)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:3431:44)

...
Here's my four tests that works fine without RouterLink in the template:
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LOJAApi } from 'my-lib';
import { EdicaoComponent } from './edicao.component';

describe('EdicaoComponent', () => {
  let component: EdicaoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EdicaoComponent>;
  let lojaService: LOJAApi;
  let router: Router;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule, EdicaoComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: LOJAApi, useValue: lojaService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: router },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: route },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EdicaoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    lojaService = TestBed.inject(LOJAApi);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return all phone info', () => {
    component.edicaoForm.value.DDD_FONE = null;
    component.edicaoForm.value.FONE = null;
    expect(component.getPhone()).toBe('00 000000000');
  });

  it('should return DDD', () => {
    component.edicaoForm.value.TELEFONE = '11999999999';
    expect(component.handleDDD()).toBe('11');
  });

  it('should return phone', () => {
    component.edicaoForm.value.TELEFONE = '11999999999';
    expect(component.handlePhone()).toBe('999999999');
  });
});


I actually just removed the providers from Router and ActivatedRoute and it worked, I didn't need then since I already had RouterTestingModule.
